# "Wrong parameters for Exception" when creating Exception subclass

Tags: php, exception, parameters

This is my code

```
class MyException extends Exception
{
   public function __construct($message, $code=0, Exception $previous = null) {
   parent::__construct($message,$code,$previous);
  }
   public function __toString() {
   return __CLASS__. ":[{$this->code}]:{$this->message}\n";
  }
}
```

Here is the error

```
Fatal error: Wrong parameters for Exception([string $exception [, long $code ]]) on line 5
```

means on this line

```
parent::__construct($message,$code,$previous);
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: `previous` parameter was added in PHP 5.3. It seems like you use older PHP version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, and on [the Exception constructor page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.construct.php), the `$previous` argument was added in PHP 5.3.

This is reflected in the error message:

> Wrong parameters for Exception **([string $exception [, long $code ]])**

PHP is being a bit zealous in making sure that the constructor matches *exactly*.  Exceptions are an important part of the internal bits, and getting them *exactly* right is worth being pedantic.

[This code demo](http://3v4l.org/Of6Vv) shows the various ways older PHP versions treat the incorrect parameter count.  From the wording used above, you're using PHP 5.1 or 5.2.

Please be aware that at time of writing this (February 2014), versions of PHP *prior to 5.4* have reached end of life for security and bug fix updates, and 5.4 is scheduled for EOL [in summer 2014](http://markmail.org/message/jzc732546bcw6pg3).

If you can, please make sure that you're using a modern version of PHP when deploying your application.